# Pushbutton doesnt enable buzzer in Tinkercad

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm trying to build this circuit in Tinkercad. The goal is to charge the capacitor and make a sound with a buzzer if the button is enabled.
[image: Circuit diagram]

The capacitor connection is suspicious because if I remove it then the buzzer works. I double-checked that the positive side is connected with the positive side of the circuit. Is there any mistake in this circuit?

[image: Circuit made in Tinkercad]

Answer (score 0):

You have the switch shorting the power supply. Move the negative leg of the capacitor and the ground over.